# Dynamically add sensors in node-red via mqtt

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, mqtt, node-red

I m a newbie with node-red, so I am looking for some directions.

I managed to display some information with node-red & node-red-contrib-ui

Using mqtt (mosquitto) topic like `RPi/out/CPU/Temperature` and payload `43` I can display a graphic and show information, save it in mongodb etc.

But the problem starts when I add 10 more sensors, DHT11 & DHT22 + DewPoint for each one of them, that makes a total of 30 graphics.

Now the question is, how can I dynamically add as many sensors as I'd like without adding nodes, wires, writing text, etc.

Does anyone has tried that? any hint? any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

If we remove the visualisation portion to start with then this is relatively simple.

Add 1 MQTT node and subscribe to a wildcard topic, e.g. `#`. This will receive all messages published. (If you can set a common root for the topics your sensors publish on it would be better than a just wildcard subscription).

Use a function node to add a timestamp to the message then pass the message thing into the mongodb node which will store it. This get's you a database that will hold all sensor data and you can create views based on the topic to get individual sensor feeds.

For the charting it gets a little bit more complicated, but since node-red-ui will plot multiple feeds (based on `msg.topic`) on the same chart with different colours then you will just need to separate out the different sensor types. Assuming the sensor type is in the topic structure then switch node should be able to do this.